# How we integrate sitemap.xml frontity reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml, frontity

I need sitemap in "http://example.com/sitemap.xml" so please give me idea how we implement in our website.

If we have a different API URL and want to use WordPress’s generated sitemap like Yoast, we can use the robot.txt file to tell the search engine about our sitemap.

Thank.